# Triggering KVO from Push Extension to App

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, key-value-observing

I am trying to implement KVO in the main app and observe when value changed by the extension.
The main app is open when push received, but no trigger in the main App. Only when I close and open it I can see the change.

Notification Class:

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?


override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {

        var user = (bestAttemptContent.userInfo["user"] as! String?)!
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test.apps")
        userDefaults!.set(user as String, forKey: "User")
        userDefaults!.synchronize()
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
}
```

Main ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test.apps")
    userDefaults!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "User", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

}

 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    //Not triggered
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test.apps")
    let user = userDefaults!.string(forKey: "User")
    NSLog("User \(user)")

}
}
```

Comment: According to apple documentation is should work after iOS 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UserDefault` for suite is not shared instance, so you have to keep it, otherwise it is just released.

Here is fixed App side controller. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

*Note: KVO works only if really new value is set, so if in your extension you set the equal value into UserDefaults, the observer won't be notified.*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // keep suite instance as member
  let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test.apps")

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userDefaults!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "User", options: [.new], context: nil)
  }

  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, 
       change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    let user = userDefaults!.string(forKey: "User")
    NSLog("User \(user)")

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you on iOS 10 or later? KVO across processes (such as extensions) didn't work until 10. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html, search for "Key-Value Observing and NSUserDefaults"

Comment: I am on target 13.2